# assign value to field using foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have two tables as follows

```
class form1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class form2(models.Model):
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    na=models.ForeignKey(form1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyskills
    def clean(self):
        keyskills=self.keyskillls
```

my views.py

```
if request.method=='POST':
        n=request.POST.get('name1')
        k=request.POST.get('key1')
        form2(na_id=n,keyskills=k).save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add')
    else:
        return render(request,"search.html")
```

search.html

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
name:<input type="text" name="name1"><br>
keyskill:<input type="text" name="key1"><br>

<input type="submit" id="click1" value="save">
</form>
```

How to assign value to name field using foreign key? , i tried but i didn't get

Comment: form2(na_id=n,keyskills=k).save() how to write this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I have to point you to the 'forms' section of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/ 
And to the documentation overall, as you're doing something really strange and wrong.